# How to get TemplateRef of a component in angular2?

Tags: angular

I have one component and need to pass your `TemplateRef` to a directive that will use `createEmbeddedView` method to replicate this component in a modal.

I tried this, but not had success.

```
<template let-ref>
    <my-component [myDirective]="ref"></my-component>
</template>
```

How i do this ?

Comment: would #ref work here?

Comment: That looks a bit weird. `myDirective` is inside the template and you want the directive create view from the template it is part of. I don't think this will work. If it could work you would need to change `let-ref` to #ref. You should be aware that `myDirective` won't be instantiated before the `<template>` is used to create an embedded view.

Comment: The `myDirective` only get the TemplateRef of component and pass to a service that create a modal and call `createEmbeddedView()`. I tried using `#ref` but no had succes.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In the template create a variable at the ng-template level:

```html
<ng-template #templateref>
  <div>Your template content</div>
</ng-template>
```

In the component use it with `@ViewChild`, it will be available `OnInit`.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my-component.html'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('templateref') public templateref: TemplateRef<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.templateref);
  }
}
```

Probably the `ViewChild` declaration can be simplified, I haven't tested it more than that.