# How to reference a component's own template defined in the @Component decorator?

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns

```
@Component({
  selector: 'base-comp',
  template: '<div>hello</div>'  <-- how to get this
})
export class BaseComponent {
  someMethod( ) {
       <-- referenced here
  }
```

I know I can use ViewChild to select a child element, but I want the entire template.
Is there a way?

Use case context:
I have 20-30 components that all extend this base comp to use commonly shared functions like date parsing/formatting and such.
10-15 of those components all have the same loading & error state config code encompassing html,css,and ts.
I want to move them all to 1 place, so figured this shared base comp would work?
Idea is to define a constructor in the base class like this:

```
  constructor(
    private readonly selfRef?: ElementRef,
  ) {
    if (this.selfRef) {
       // attach this.template containing loading & error state html
       // via Renderer2 or .nativeElement or something
    }
  }
```

and attach it to the extender component's elementRef, thereby consolidating that bit of code into 1 place.
the css for this is a `position: absolute` overlay so it should just cover the extender comp.

Also open to alterative solutions for this effort.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the ng-template element with TemplateRef.
Response from [How to get TemplateRef of a component in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880420/how-to-get-templateref-of-a-component-in-angular2)

component-name.html

```
<template>
  <ng-template #templateref>
    <div>Your template content</div>
  </ng-template>
</template>
```

component-name.ts

```
export class ComponentName {
  @ViewChild('templateref') public templateref: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```